# Mathematica export to avi plays forwards, then backwards

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I'm modelling the gravity field of the eight planets and trying to export the resulting ContourPlot as a .avi file. The problem is that the .avi plays the animation both forwards and backwards, even though I explicitly tell Animate that AnimationDirection->Forward. Anyone know any solutions? Here's the offending piece of code:

```
gfield = Animate[
  ContourPlot[
   Sqrt[Fgravplanets[x, y, t][[1]]^2 + Fgravplanets[x, y, t][[2]]^2],
   {x, -1.5 rp["Neptune"], 1.5 rp["Neptune"]}, {y, -1.5 rp["Neptune"],
     1.5 rp["Neptune"]},
   PlotRange -> {0, 10},
   Mesh -> None,
   ImageSize -> Medium,
   AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "Fgrav"},
   ColorFunction -> Hue,
   PlotPoints -> 20,
   Contours -> 20
   ],
  {t, 0, 365*24*3600*10, 365*24*3600/10},
  AnimationDirection -> Forward,
  AnimationRate -> 365*24*3600/5
  ]
Export["gfield.avi", gfield]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace `Animate` by `Table`:

```
gfield = Table[
   ContourPlot[
   Sqrt[Fgravplanets[x, y, t][[1]]^2 + Fgravplanets[x, y, t][[2]]^2],
   {x, -1.5 rp["Neptune"], 1.5 rp["Neptune"]}, {y, -1.5 rp["Neptune"],
    1.5 rp["Neptune"]},
   PlotRange -> {0, 10},
   Mesh -> None,
   ImageSize -> Medium,
   AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "Fgrav"},
   ColorFunction -> Hue,
   PlotPoints -> 20,
   Contours -> 20
   ],
 {t, 0, 365*24*3600*10, 365*24*3600/10}];

Export["gfield.avi", gfield]
```

Exporting to .avi works as expected for lists of graphics. You might have to adjust the step size in the `Table` iterator to achieve your desired framerate.